# Single method to launch a coroutine

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have a StorageRepository that talks with RoomDB and also shared prefs. I want this communication to happen through a single method on a IO thread. I have done this until now -

```
class StorageRepository(private val coroutineDispatcher: CoroutineContext = Dispatchers.Main
) : CoroutineScope {

    private val job = Job()

    override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
        get() = job + coroutineDispatcher

    override fun storeUserDetails(userDetails: UserDetails) {
        roomDB.store(userDetails)
    }

    override fun storeTimeStamp(timeStamp: String) {
        sharedPrefs.store(timeStamp)
    }

    private fun executeAllOpsOnIOThread() = launch {
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            //Any DB write, read operations to be done here
        }
    }
}
```

My question is how can I pass `roomDB.store(userDetails)` and `sharedPrefs.store(timeStamp)` to `executeAllOpsOnIOThread()` so that all DB communication happens on IO thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm.. Maybe I misunderstand you but it seems you can just pass a block of code as lambda function like this:

```
class StorageRepository(
    private val coroutineDispatcher: CoroutineContext = Dispatchers.Main
) : CoroutineScope {

    private val job = Job()

    override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
        get() = job + coroutineDispatcher

    override fun storeUserDetails(userDetails: UserDetails) = executeAllOpsOnIOThread {
        roomDB.store(userDetails)
    }

    override fun storeTimeStamp(timeStamp: String) = executeAllOpsOnIOThread {
        sharedPrefs.store(timeStamp)
    }

    private fun executeAllOpsOnIOThread(block: () -> Unit) = launch {
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            block()
        }
    }

    //async get
    fun getTimestamp(): Deferred<String> = getOnIOThread { sharedPrefs.getTime() }

    private fun <T> getOnIOThread(block: () -> T):Deferred<T> = async {
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            block()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you that works fine :) But how is it when I have a read method that returns a value... For example returnTimeStamp I do like this val timestamp = executeAllOpsOnIOThread { sharedPrefs.getTime() } return timestamp but it says need to return string but found Job

Comment: Cool!Thanks a lot

Comment: Jus a last question, sorry. With this Deferred<String>, if I use await() to get the actual String, it says I can only use await() from suspend function. How could I do this?

Comment: Sorry I found it myself :)